# jquery mobile changePage() loads only first page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dom, mobile, navigation

I recently started working with JQuery Mobile and so far I find it a great tool to work with.
It works smooth and fast, and is easy managable considering the UI.

However, I'm stumbling across some difficulties now which is:

1. I have an application that requires the user to login using an email and password.
   Therefore I have included the login and account creation part in the index.html. The application itself (app.html) is placed in a seperate folder named Application, this folder has an .htaccess file that should block direct access to is (didn't manage to solve this yet).
2. When the user is logged in, (this will be checked by sending the accountId, sessionId (created at serverside) to the server which will return true or false). If false, the application will redirect the user to the index.html again.

However the weird part is, that when the user is logged in and redirected to the app.html page, it only loads the first page .

```
<div data-role="page" id="menu">
```

This is strange because there should be like 10 pages in the DOM, but it doesnt show these when pressing F12 to preview the generated DOM.

Next to this, it's still showing the login and createaccount page in the DOM.

This is how I navigate to the new page:

```
$.mobile.changePage("Application/app.html", { transition: "slidefade", changeHash: false });
```

---

Incidentally, this is what the DOM looks like after navigating:

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
<div data-role="page" id="createaccount" data-url="createaccount">...</div>
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu1" data-url="/Application/app.html" data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active">...</div>
</body>
```

Expected result:

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
<div data-role="page" id="menu1" data-url="/Application/app.html" data-external-page="true" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu2" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu3" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu4" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu5" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu6" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu7" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu8" data-url="/Application/app.html">...</div>
</body>
```

---

When manipulating the DOM by editing the code using F12, and create a page with the ID which is shown in an menu item..

It navigates to the page, but the previous page is removed from the DOM, which makes it look like an 'active page' issue.

Comment: how do you redirect user to index.html, `changePage`? if yes try `$.mobile.changePage('index.html', { reloadPage: true });`. Which jQM version are you using?

Comment: The User is never really returned to the index page again, only when he's trying to access the app.html page, because it's an 'logged in required' section. However, because the changePage is currently not working, I have disabled the authorizing part, but at the moment im at a point I need to re-enable it.

I'm using jQM 1.3.2

Comment: `$.mobile.changePage("Application/app.html", { transition: "slidefade", changeHash: false, reloadPage: true });` sorry I thought user is being directed to index.

Comment: The output is the same, still only the active page is shown in the DOM, which disables navigation to the other pages.

Comment: ok try `$.mobile.loadPage('Application/app.html');` and then `$.mobile.changePage('#menu1');`

Comment: Now it is manipulating the DOM (aka: It adds the page with id 'menu1' to the DOM), but now its not even setting it as the active page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38867/discussion-between-larssy1-and-omar)

Comment: check chat whenever you can.

Comment: Would you be interested in creating pages (menus) dynamically once login is successful?

Comment: If it were a small application sure, but I'm going to have between 20-50 pages. Creating all of these pages dynamically would take lots of code to create them, which will increase load time.

Comment: Lets discuss it on chat